# How do I prove this in Lean? p ∨ ¬p

Tags: logic, lean

I have a theorem to prove on lean,

```
theorem T (h : ¬ A) : ¬ (A ∨ B) ∨ (¬ A ∧ B)
```

For which to prove, I guess, I need to use,

```
or.elim (B ∨ ¬B) (assume b: B, ...) (assume nb:¬B, ...)
```

For which, again, I have to prove

```
B v ¬B
```

So, how do I proceed with this? Is there any better method?

Comment: This isn't provable without the optional extra axiom `classical.choice`. As Mario says below the name of the theorem in the library is `classical.em`

Answer (score 2):

`p v ¬p` is a lemma from the core library called `classical.em`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tactic

variables (A B : Prop)

theorem T (h : ¬ A) : ¬ (A ∨ B) ∨ (¬ A ∧ B) := by tauto!
```